# dimension and base of arithmetic sequence

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, vector-spaces

Arithmetic sequence is a vector space. But how to find a dimension of it. 
I try this: arithmetic sequence:
$a_1,a_2,...,a_n={a_1,(a_1+d),(a_1+2d),...,(a_n+(n-1)d)}$

With only $a_1$ and $d=(a_1-a_2$) I can show every member of arithmetic sequence.
$(a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_n)=a_1(1,1...,1)+d(0,1,2,3...,n-1)$ 
Vectors $(1,1...,1) $ and $ (0,1,2,3...,n-1)$ are lineary independent so base for arithmetic sequence is [(1,1...,1),(0,1,2,3...,n-1)] and $dim$ of vector space in number of element in base, so $dim=2$ 
Is this ok?